# Queue of Threads in pthread C - web server repsonse pipelining

Tags: c, multithreading, data-structures, server, pthreads

I have a working HTTP Apache-like web server implemented in C, and my problem is that I don't know how to initialize the queue (and therefore how to enqueue threads into it), mostly because I'm not sure how to check if there is a previous thread to join before proceeding with the current one.

The server can exploit pipeline requests to increase its response speed, using threads in a
more sophisticated way: the web server can generate a new thread for each request for a new
resource, and simultaneously prepare responses; however, since the resources must be returned
to the client in the same order in which the requests were received by the server (FIFO), it will
take a coordination phase between the various response threads.

This coordination phase is achieved by implementing a sort of "waiting room for the doctor"
in which each patient, when entering, asks who was the last to arrive, keeps track of it and
enters the doctor's office only when the person in front of him leaves. In this way, everyone has
a partial view of the queue (cares for only one person) but this partial view allows a correct
implementation of a FIFO queue.

Here is the description of what do I have to do:

*Likewise, each new thread will have to store the identifier of the thread that handles the previous
request and wait for its termination using the system call pthread_join (). The first thread,
obviously, will not have to wait for anyone and the last thread will have to be waited by the main
thread that handles the requests on that connection before closing the connection itself and
returning to wait for new connection requests.*

I am having trouble **initializing properly the to_join data structure**, mostly because I don't understand how to compute the index i of the thread to join.- how can I differenciate the first and last thread in an array of pointers?

Here is the code (I could only modify in between the TO BE DONE START and TO BE DONE END comments):

```
#include "incApache.h"

pthread_mutex_t accept_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mime_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int client_sockets[MAX_CONNECTIONS]; /* for each connection, its socket FD */
int no_response_threads[MAX_CONNECTIONS]; /* for each connection, how many response threads */

pthread_t thread_ids[MAX_THREADS];
int connection_no[MAX_THREADS]; /* connection_no[i] >= 0 means that i-th thread belongs to connection connection_no[i] */
pthread_t *to_join[MAX_THREADS]; /* for each thread, the pointer to the previous (response) thread, if any */

int no_free_threads = MAX_THREADS - 2 * MAX_CONNECTIONS; /* each connection has one thread listening and one reserved for replies */
struct response_params thread_params[MAX_THREADS - MAX_CONNECTIONS]; /* params for the response threads (the first MAX_CONNECTIONS threads are waiting/parsing requests) */

pthread_mutex_t threads_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; /* protects the access to thread-related data structures */

pthread_t thread_ids[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
int connection_no[MAX_CONNECTIONS];

void *client_connection_thread(void *vp) {
    int client_fd;
    struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&threads_mutex);
    int connection_no = *((int *) vp);

    /*** properly initialize the thread queue to_join ***/
/*** TO BE DONE 3.1 START ***/
        //to_join[0] = thread_ids[new_thread_idx];
    //pthread_t *first;     Am I perhaps supposed to initialize the to_join data structure as a queue with two pointers
    //pthread_t *last;      indicating the first and last element? How can I do it on an array of pointers?
/*** TO BE DONE 3.1 END ***/

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&threads_mutex);
#endif
    for (;;) {
        addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&accept_mutex);
        if ((client_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &addr_size)) == -1)
            fail_errno("Cannot accept client connection");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&accept_mutex);
        client_sockets[connection_no] = client_fd;
        char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) &client_addr;
        printf("Accepted connection from %s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(ipv4->sin_addr), str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN));
        manage_http_requests(client_fd
                , connection_no);
    }
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
void send_resp_thread(int out_socket, int response_code, int cookie,
              int is_http1_0, int connection_idx, int new_thread_idx,
              char *filename, struct stat *stat_p)
{
    struct response_params *params =  thread_params + (new_thread_idx - MAX_CONNECTIONS);
    debug(" ... send_resp_thread(): idx=%lu\n", (unsigned long)(params - thread_params));
    params->code = response_code;
    params->cookie = cookie;
    params->is_http1_0 = is_http1_0;
    params->filename = filename ? my_strdup(filename) : NULL;
    params->p_stat = stat_p;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&threads_mutex);
    connection_no[new_thread_idx] = connection_idx;
    debug(" ... send_resp_thread(): parameters set, conn_no=%d\n", connection_idx);

    /*** enqueue the current thread in the "to_join" data structure ***/
/*** TO BE DONE 3.1 START ***/
    //Again, should I use a standard enqueue implementation? But then how would I keep track of the last node ot arrive?
/*** TO BE DONE 3.1 END ***/

    if (pthread_create(thread_ids + new_thread_idx, NULL, response_thread, connection_no + new_thread_idx))
        fail_errno("Could not create response thread");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&threads_mutex);
    debug(" ... send_resp_thread(): new thread created\n");
}

void *response_thread(void *vp)
{
    size_t thread_no = ((int *) vp) - connection_no;
    int connection_idx = *((int *) vp);
    debug(" ... response_thread() thread_no=%lu, conn_no=%d\n", (unsigned long) thread_no, connection_idx);
    const size_t i = thread_no - MAX_CONNECTIONS;
    send_response(client_sockets[connection_idx],
              thread_params[i].code,
              thread_params[i].cookie,
              thread_params[i].is_http1_0,
              (int)thread_no,
              thread_params[i].filename,
              thread_params[i].p_stat);
    debug(" ... response_thread() freeing filename and stat\n");
    free(thread_params[i].filename);
    free(thread_params[i].p_stat);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You're having trouble in large part because the design you're trying to implement has many problems. They start with heavy reliance on file-scope data structures, but do not by any means end there.  The particular details you are asking about appear to arise from the fact that you have no data structure associating threads or tasks with the client connection / request for which they are presently performing work.

Comment: To use a thread pool effectively, you need to better decouple the work to be done from the threads that are performing it.  I would suggest one or more queues or priority queues of tasks, from which the worker threads draw.  Ordering associations should be created between tasks where needed, not between threads.  Implement data in each task-description structure that supports the thread(s) managing responses holding off on writing before each task has been completed and all the others have been rendered that must be rendered before.  `pthread_join()` has pretty much nothing to do with it.

Comment: Note that any solution relying on `pthread_join()` cannot be described as using a thread *pool*, because `pthread_join` awaits a thread's termination, whereas the key characteristic of a thread pool is that each thread in it can perform multiple pieces of work.  Once a thread terminates, it cannot perform any more work.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation @JohnBollinger. I modified the question accordingly to your last comment, as I misunderstood the correct use of a thread pool.

Comment: Do you perhaps know how could I work on initializing such "data structure", keeping in mind that unfortunately I cna only write code in between the comments TO BE DONE START and TO BE DONE END?

Comment: Having looked at the code more closely, something is very screwey here.  There are two declarations of `connection_no` at file scope with (apparently) different array lengths, which produces undefined behavior.  Moreover, at least one of those is relevant to the task, but it is inaccessible in the function because its identifier is shadowed by the name of a local variable.  I suspect I'm looking at a hodge-podge of parts that are not intended to be combined in this way, but whatever the origin of these issues, the question is unanswerable as it stands.

Comment: I agree (it creates quite a few warnings when compiled), unfortunately the code has been provided by my professor and it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am having trouble **initializing properly the to_join data structure**,
>   mostly because I don't understand how to compute the index i of the
>   thread to join.- how can I differenciate the first and last thread in
>   an array of pointers?

Assignment is different from initialization, and operating on one element is different from operating on the whole array.  As far as I can determine, you're not actually to initialize `to_join` in that function (so the comment is misleading).  Instead, you're only to assign an appropriate value to a single element.

That analysis follows from my interpretation of the names, scope, and documentation comments of the various global variables and from the name, signature, and initial lines of the function in question:

- it appears that the various arrays hold data pertaining to multiple threads of multiple connections, as the role of one of the file-scope `connection_no` arrays is to associate threads with connections.
- it appears that the function is meant to be the thread-start function for connection-associated threads.
- no thread started at a time when any other connection-associated threads are running should do anything other than set data pertaining to itself, lest it clobber data on which other threads and connections rely.

Now, as for the actual question -- how do you determine which thread the new one should join?  **You can't**.  At least, not relying only on the template code presented in the question, unmodified.<sup>*</sup>

*Hypothetically*, if you could access the version of the `connection_no` array that associates threads with connections then you could use it to find the indexes of all threads associated with the current connection.  You could then get their thread IDs from the corresponding `thread_ids` array (noting that there is another name collision here), and their join targets from the `join_to` array.  The first thread for the connection is the one that does not join to another, and the last is the one that is not joined by any other.  That analysis is not altogether straightforward, but there are no real tricks to it.  Details are left as the exercise they are meant to be.

But even if the file-scope name collisions were resolved, you could not perform the above analysis because the file-scope `connection_no` array is shadowed by a local variable of the same name inside the whole area where you are permitted to insert code.<sup>*</sup>

Note also that you appear to need to choose a thread index for the new thread, which in general will not be 0.  It looks like you need to scan the `thread_ids` or `connection_no` array to find an available index.

---

<sup>*</sup>***Unless you cheat***.  I take the intent to be for you to insert code (only) into the body of the `client_connection_thread` function, but you could, in fact, split that function into two or more by inserting code into the designated area.  If the second file-scope declarations of `connection_no` and `thread_ids` were assumed to be ignored or missing in practice, then splitting up the function could provide a workaround for the shadowing issue.  For example:

```
    /*** properly initialize the thread queue to_join ***/
/*** TO BE DONE 3.1 START ***/

    return client_connection_thread_helper1(connection_no);
}  // end of function

// parameter 'con' is the number of this thread's connection
void *client_connection_thread_helper1(int con) {
    int my_index;
    // ... Find an available thread index (TODO: what if there isn't one?) ...
    thread_ids[my_index] = pthread_self();
    connection_no[my_index] = con;  // connection_no is not shadowed in this scope

    pthread_t *last = NULL;
    // ... Find the last (other) thread associated with connection 'con', if any ...
    // You can determine the first, too, but that does not appear to be required.

    to_join[my_index] = last;

    return client_connection_thread_helper2(con);
}

// A second additional function is required for the remaining bits of
// client_connection_thread(), because they need the local connection_no
void *client_connection_thread_helper2(int connection_no) {
    int client_fd;
    struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
    socklen_t addr_size;

/*** TO BE DONE 3.1 END ***/


    pthread_mutex_unlock(&threads_mutex);
```

I suppose it is possible that figuring out the need and implementation for such function-splitting was intended to be part of the exercise, but that would be a dirty trick, and overall it seems more likely that the exercise is just poorly formed.